# Call javascript function from agent

Tags: javascript, agent

How can I call a javascript function from a Lotus Notes agent? As far as it is possible at all. Lotusscript Agent? Java Agent?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A javascript function performs some actions on the client (user browser). A lotus agent runs on the server. So, I can't see how you can be benefited from such a call (which of course is not possible).

Comment: In my limited view concerning my function, I wanted this so bad... but as you explain it this way, it makes sense.